# Swipe back on iOS Web result in janky animation

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

I am using Flutter GoRouter to navigate from the Homespace with path `/` to a search page with path `/search`. I transition to the search page via `context.go('/search')`.

From the search page when I swipe back, I get a weird animation albeit I am in the correct page.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by following this [recipe on Github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/114324#issuecomment-1725887254).